# Regex to match only letters and numbers

Tags: java, regex

Can you help with this code?

It seems easy, but always fails.

```
@Test
public void normalizeString(){
    StringBuilder ret =  new StringBuilder();
    //Matcher matches = Pattern.compile( "([A-Z0-9])" ).matcher("P-12345678-P");
    Matcher matches = Pattern.compile( "([\\w])" ).matcher("P-12345678-P");
    for (int i = 1; i < matches.groupCount(); i++)
        ret.append(matches.group(i));

    assertEquals("P12345678P", ret.toString());
}
```

Comment: You need to call `Matcher.matches()` or `Matcher.find()` before calling `groupCount()`

Comment: Instead of trying to match each part that contains letters and digits, the way is to perform a replacement of characters that are not letters or digits.

Comment: Also please note that the `_` is also matched by `\w` (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_wordchar.asp), but no non-ASCII letters.

Comment: "but always fails" can you be more precise so people with same problem would be able to actually google potential solutions (if they appear) via some keywords like name of exception you are getting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Constructing a `Matcher` does not automatically perform any matching.  That's in part because `Matcher` supports two distinct matching behaviors, differing in whether the match is implicitly anchored to the beginning of the `Matcher`'s region.  It appears that you could achieve your desired result like so:

```
@Test
public void normalizeString(){
    StringBuilder ret =  new StringBuilder();
    Matcher matches = Pattern.compile( "[A-Z0-9]+" ).matcher("P-12345678-P");

    while (matches.find()) {
        ret.append(matches.group());
    }

    assertEquals("P12345678P", ret.toString());
}
```

Note in particular the invocation of `Matcher.find()`, which was a key omission from your version.  Also, the nullary `Matcher.group()` returns the substring matched by the last `find()`.

Furthermore, although your use of `Matcher.groupCount()` isn't exactly wrong, it does lead me suspect that you have the wrong idea about what it does.  In particular, in your code it will always return `1` -- it inquires about the *pattern*, not about matches to it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to add any group because entire match can be always accessed by group 0, so instead of

- `(regex)` and `group(1)`

you can use

- `regex` and `group(0)`

Next thing is that `\\w` is already [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) so you don't need to surround it with another `[` `]`, because it will be similar to `[[a-z]]` which is same as `[a-z]`.

Now in your

```
for (int i = 1; i < matches.groupCount(); i++)
    ret.append(matches.group(i));
```

you will iterate over all groups from `1` but you will exclude last group, because they are indexed from `1` so `n` so `i<n` will not include `n`. You would need to use `i <= matches.groupCount()` instead.

Also it looks like you are confusing something. This loop will not find all matches of regex in input. Such loop is used to iterate over groups in used regex ***after match for regex was found***.

So if regex would be something like `(\w(\w))c` and your match would be like `abc` then

```
for (int i = 1; i < matches.groupCount(); i++)
    System.out.println(matches.group(i));
```

would print

```
ab
b
```

because

- first group contains two characters `(\w(\w))` before `c`
- second group is the one inside first one, right after first character.

But to print them you actually would need to first let regex engine iterate over your input and `find()` match, or check if entire input `matches()` regex, otherwise you would get `IllegalStateException` because regex engine can't know from which match you want to get your groups (there can be many matches of regex in input).

So what you may want to use is something like

```
StringBuilder ret =  new StringBuilder();
Matcher matches = Pattern.compile( "[A-Z0-9]" ).matcher("P-12345678-P");
while (matches.find()){//find next match
    ret.append(matches.group(0));
}
assertEquals("P12345678P", ret.toString());
```

---

Other way around (and probably simpler solution) would be actually removing all characters you don't want from your input. So you could just use `replaceAll` and negated character class `[^...]` like

```
String input = "P-12345678-P";
String result = input.replaceAll("[^A-Z0-9]+", "");
```

which will produce new string in which all characters which are not `A-Z0-9` will be removed (replaced with `""`).